# odd newbie question about "sketching" at the table?

Tags: etiquette

I am thinking of getting into poker. I like to draw / sketch as well. What do you all think about the idea of "sketching" at the poker table when sitting out a hand ? Would that be totally horrible etiquette ? Would it be a fun curiosity ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that would probably come as disrespectful. Not to mention that if you want to be successful in your games, you should be paying attention to what's going on at the table.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen people do this before, in my case they would usually draw/sketch on their phone or an ipad when they are out of a hand. I do not find it to be bad etiquette as long as they are paying attention to the action and not causing delays. @David makes a great point by mentioning you should pay attention to what's going on at the table if you want to be successful. Nevertheless, lots of people in live poker sit on their phones the entire time so I don't think it would be disrespectful to most people, although you may run into someone who has a problem with it.

Comment: Yah I was wondering if people would take it sort of as being on your phone the whole time.

Comment: I think you'll get a bit more curiosity from people than someone on their phone. But as said above by David and Clarko, just don't slow the game down and you'll be fine. You'll also be missing a lot of information if you want to be successful.

Comment: yea that's the flip side of the coin huh ? Not analyzing people's play. Anyhow thanks for the perspectives.